# How can an AAR library be substituted for another implementation module?

Tags: gradle

I have a file 'libs/mylib.aar' that should replace OkHttp in react native. I am using something like this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp') using module('com.blah.example:mylib:1.0@aar')
    }
}
```

And in settings.gradle I have

```
include ':myproj'
project(':myproj').projectDir = new File('libs/')
```